# Laravel 5.1 - retrieving a polymorphic association with WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.1, polymorphic-associations

I'm having trouble retrieving a polymorphic association "where related_object.column_name = x". Let me explain:

I have a number of “pages" in my database, and each page has polymorphic association to different types of “content”. for example :

**pages**

slug : my-page, id : 1

slug : my-other page, id: 2

**music_track table**

music_track : id 10, page_id : 1

**video table**

video : id 20, page_id: 2

**image table**

image : id 30, page_id: 1

**content table**

id: 555, contentable_id 10, contentable_type: App\music_track

id: 556, contentable_id 20, contentable_type: App\video

id: 557, contentable_id 30, contentable_type: App\image

I can return all content using Content::all( ), how do I return all content who’s page_id is ‘1’?

I can't seem to use Content::where('page_id', "=", "1"), because page_id is ambiguous, or assumed to be part of the content table. How to a query the RELATED table?

Comment: Do you have all the relationships defined inside of your models?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Put this method inside of your `MusicTrack`, `Image` and `Video` models:

```
/**
 * Return a list of related models based on page id
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query 
 * @param int $id 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeOfPage($query, $id)
{
    return $query->where('page_id', $id);
}
```

Then if you have all relationships inside of your `Page` model:

```
$images = $page->images()->ofPage($id)->get();
//
$music_tracks = $page->music()->ofPage($id)->get();
//
$videos = $page->videos()->ofPage($id)->get();
```

If you don't have them, then:

```
/**
 * Return a list of images which are included in this page.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Image', 'contentable');
}

/**
 * Return a list of music tracks which are included in this page.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function music()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Music', 'contentable');
}

/**
 * Return a list of music tracks which are included in this page.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function videos()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Video', 'contentable');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very clever, but I want to return $content where page_id = $id. The above result can be simply achieved with Video::where('page_id', '=', $id)